# create the object of json and pass data to the server using the VBScipt

Tags: java, json, vbscript, restful-authentication

I am beginner to develop that find of the webservice so please help to solve my problem

I need to create the one VBS(VBScript) file in that the how to create the json string and that the json object pass to the java restful webservice

below is the my code but it's not a json form so please help to create the json form of a object

```
surl="http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello/add"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network") 
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName 
json="name="+strComputer+"&age=24"
'json="name=strComputer&age=24"
HTTPPost sUrl,json
Function HTTPPost(sUrl,json)

'Microsoft.XMLHTTP
set OHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
OHTTP.open "POST",surl,false
msgbox(surl & json)


OHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
OHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length","Len(json)"
OHTTP.setRequestHeader "Pragma","no-cache"
OHTTP.setRequestHeader "Expires","-1"
OHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection","close"

OHTTP.send json

'HTTPPOST = oHTTP.responseText
msgbox(OHTTP.responseText)
End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your valueable time spend on my problem

Answer (score 1):

This will be helpful:

http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/